# Use ARRAYFORMULA with horizontal COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets, countif, array-formulas

I am using `COUNTIF` to count the number of occurrences of a value in a horizontal range, which is working fine:

[image]

Now I would like to use `ARRAYFORMULA` to automatically apply that logic to an entire column. My problem is that `ARRAYFORMULA` doesn't seem to work well with `COUNTIF` as my range spans both horizontally and vertically. I tried several things:

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(B2:D,"Passed")=3,"Passed","Failed"))` : the formula doesn't even replicate across the column
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",IF(COUNTIF(B2:D,"Passed")=3,"Passed","Failed")))` : using the extra `IF(ISBLANK(B2:B)` trick solves the above issue, but the results are wrong

[image]

**How can I apply `ARRAYFORMULA` to a formula containing a horizontal `COUNTIF`?**

[Here is a link to the spreadsheet if you want to play around](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17X50F6HAq3O7g1_F6HdicllGuYAT3uoqkPqaiMuAdUI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: in a each row I should count occurrences of a symbol in a given horizontal range, using this formula: `=if(countif(V2:X2,"■") = 1,Acorn1,if(countif(V2:X2,"■") = 2,Acorn2,if(countif(V2:X2,"■") = 3,Acorn3,"")))`. What arrayformula should I use to expand vertically?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not on my todo list anymore. You can check @pnuts ' answer and let me know if it works, that way I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
=if(arrayformula(len(B2:B)*(B2:B="P")*(C2:C="P")*(D2:D="P")),"Passed","Failed")
```